# Executables not found and autocompletion not working with meta-ros

Tags: ros, binaries, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a many systems running meta-ros according to https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros/ instructions. In all of them, ROS seems to work OK. However, one of them cannot find nodes executables. For instance, the joy package is correctly installed and I can run by doing `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/joy/joy_node`. However, if I try `rosrun joy joy_node` the output is:

`[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named joy_node below /opt/ros/indigo/share/joy`

The executable is actually in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/joy`.

I have compared both systems, and all the environment variables are the same. However, this one in which it does not work does not have `/opt/ros/indigo/include` folder for instance. That is the only difference I can find, apart from some different packages.

I have also run `rospack profile`

Do you have any suggestion on what to try? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216048/executables-not-found-and-autocompletion-not-working-with-meta-ros/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem: for some reason, the `catkin_find` command which is executed in rosrun script was not installed. A bit weird, since other packages depend on this one.

Anyway, [installing catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin), in my case `opkg install catkin` solved the problem.

*EDIT*: I had the problem again on a different platform and I had to do:
`source /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbash/rosbash` to make it work.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-06**:
Have you reported this to the `meta-ros` [issue tracker](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros/issues)?

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-05-30**:
Hi!

i encountered the same problem. but i have already installed catkin. i did the `source /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbash/rosbash` but joy_node still could not be seen when i do the rosrun joy joy_node

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2017-05-31**:
@fj138696 I recommend you to create a new question giving more details about your case (platform, what are you running and how, output, etc).